# Rails Admin form for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

For instance say, I have an association in one of my model as:

```
has_many :students
```

We know `rails_admin` creates a multi-selection input field in the form where a user can select students.

The multi-selection input lists all the students.

My question is, is there a way to filter those students and only list out some students that satisfy some condition? If there is, how should I proceed? For example, I want to list out only the students who are let's say active.

There are 100 students and 75 of them are active. I want only those 75 to be listed.

In the screenshot below, I want only Demo projects to be displayed on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can scope the association like this

```
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :students do
        associated_collection_scope do
          class_room = bindings[:object]

          proc { |scope| scope.where(class_room: class_room) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use scopes in your parent Model.

Read this for [Scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)
Read this for `rails_admin` [Scopes](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List#scopes)

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :students
  scope :active_students, -> { where(active: true) }
end
```

Then you can use it like:

`Teacher.first.active_students`

**UPDATE:**

You have to customize specifically that field of `students` by using custom field like mentioned [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#form-rendering)

Comment: There is a field keeping tag of which student is active and which is not. I also have understanding of scope and how we can use it. My question however is about rails_admin generated form. How do I use the scope to solve my problem? I have specified about the rails admin. I have edited the question and added a screenshot to elaborate my question.

Comment: let me show you how to do that. Meanwhile please add `rails_admin form code` as well

Comment: `rails_admin` form code? rails_admin generates the code automatically. There is no view for the form. Since the action is not custom, I have not written custom form. The form is auto-generated.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544398/scopes-as-filters-in-rails-admin

Comment: I have added an update. You have to customize your field and add logic to your custom field_form

Comment: The thread you referenced is different from my question. He is trying to add a tab/button to filter the contents. He is talking about filtering the index (list) using the scope as filter. Meaning he wants a button which he can click and get only the `unconfirmed` users. Yes I am talking about filtering but I want to filter the list that has_many association creates in the form.

Comment: I am talking about this https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#form-rendering

Comment: Yes. I was talking about the StackOverflow thread link that you shared. I will take a look at the rails_admin wiki that you referenced. Thanks for the wiki link